# Объясните паттерн mvp в android

Tags: java, android, mvp

Объясните пожалуйста паттерн mvp.

Mvc - понятно, есть модель, есть контроллер и есть вью (xml), а вот как в mvp это все не пойму.

Пожалуйста с примерами кода, а то чувствую, что пора писать чистый код, и нужно двигаться вперед.

Answer (score 7):

Главное отличие **MVP** от **MVC**: в **MVP** представление определяет презентер, а не наоборот. А в **MVC** контроллер контролирует ввод данных пользователем и использует модель и представление для реализации необходимой реакции.

Также отличаются условия использования этих паттернов. MVC применяется там, где представление обновляется каждый раз по какому-либо событию, а MVP применяется, когда представление не нужно каждый раз пересоздавать.

Ещё важное отличие MVP и MVC заключается в том, что обычно в MVP между представлением и презентером существует связь один к одному, с возможностью использования нескольких презентеров для сложных представлений. В то время как в MVC один контроллер могут использовать несколько представлений.

И вот достаточно хороший [пример](https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/android-basic-project-architecture-for-mvp-72f4b33252d0) кода.

Comment: А пример кода mvp?

Comment: Очень интересная тема. А можно чуть более упрощенно назвать разницу между MVC и MVP?